# Run Gradle from intelliJ as administrator

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, gradle

Here's my problem: Recently I started using IntelliJ and I imported a gradle project. Normally, I would execute some gradle commands in an elevated command prompt (i.e run cmd as administrator) because of some operations that require it. Now I have set up run configuration in intelliJ but I do not know how to make this configuration run as an administrator.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, running the whole idea as administrator seems to solve the problem. I feel silly for not trying this in the first place.....